# Diminished chord terminology

Tags: chords, terminology

What’s the terminology for changing a major triad into a diminished chord?
C major – C°7 – Gmin7 – C7 etc.

I can’t remember the term!

Answer (score 2):

It's called a common-tone diminished chord. For more on common-tone diminished chords, see [Understanding function of diminished chord in Paganini's 4th caprice](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/107886/70803).

However, in the specific case presented, the chord labeled as C<sup>o7</sup> would actually be F#<sup>o7</sup>, because it's leading to the G chord. That is, the diminished chord is the leading-tone diminished chord for G minor.

Comment: Thanks ! 
F# °7 and then specify the inversion if I want the root to be C on both chords . 

C - C#°7  becomes C - f# °4/2