# Harmonic Analysis of Polka, Op. 39, No. 14 by Tchaikovsky

Tags: harmony, analysis

I'm having some trouble identifying what's going on harmonically in this chromatic sections here.

i. Bar 2: What function does the chord spelled `[C#EGBb]` have? All I can say about it is that it's a fully diminished chord built on either the 1st, b3rd, #4th, or 6th scale degree. But I can't slot any of these into what I know about music theory.

ii Bar 10 (i.e. the last bar of line 2): The chord spelled `[G#FB]`. Enharmonically this would be an Fdim. But it's spelled with G# instead of Ab so I don't want to jump to that conclusion. Aside from that, I wouldn't know what harmonic purposes an Fdim could serve here.

Thanks

As background, I'm a hobbyist piano player who's trying to get a better understanding of what I'm playing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both chords in question are instances of *common-tone* diminished chords. These are chords that serve to prolong, expand, or, in this case, delay the arrival of a principal harmony with which there is a shared pitch — typically the root of the principal harmony.

In m. 2, the common tone is the. `Bb` between the first and second chords of that measure. In m. 10, the common tone is the `F` between the first and second chords. In both cases, the diminished chords are spelled enharmonically to make clear the chromatic motion in the bass.

More on common-tone chords can be found in:

- [Diminished chord constructed over the tonic degree?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/86798/diminished-chord-constructed-over-the-tonic-degree)
- [A chord progression from Leavitt: how to analyze it correctly](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104303/a-chord-progression-from-leavitt-how-to-analyze-it-correctly/104304#10430)
- [How does this Bdim7 resolves to F/C?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/105128/how-does-this-bdim7-resolves-to-f-c)
- [Is this a harmonic sequence?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104437/is-this-a-harmonic-sequence)
- [What's going on functionally/structurally in these four bars of Rachmaninoff's 3rd piano concerto?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/whats-going-on-functionally-structurally-in-these-four-bars-of-rachmaninoffs-3)
- [Where does the Eb diminished 7 in I Wanna Be Around come from and how to play over it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/79539/where-does-the-eb-diminished-7-in-i-wanna-be-around-come-from-and-how-to-play-ov)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This makes sense. What threw me here is that some of the texts I've seen specified that a common-tone diminished chord must be nested between two identical chords - e.g. an I6 on both sides. This didn't happen in this case. But I just found two sources saying that this CTo7 can happen with incomplete neighbor tones.

Answer (score 2):

Bars 1-2 are basically this:
[image]
one of the most common harmonic cliches throughout Common Practice music!   The diminished chord is used as a chromatic link.  It COULD have been used as a modulation to D minor, in which case we could have analyzed C♯dim7  as a rootless A7(♭9), the dominant of D minor.  But in this case there's no modulation, it's just a passing chord.

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on the request for a functional interpretation of the first question using Riemannian music theory which is the foundation of Functional Harmonic Theory. The C#o7 chord as was mentioned in another answer can be taken as an A7 chord (or an A7b9). The question is A7 of what key; it is A7 of either D major or D minor; in this case we can take it as A7 of D minor. The A7 however does not resolve to D minor, but rather it moves to Bb major. Bb major does in fact have a functional relationship to D minor; it is the Tonic Leittonwechsel of D minor (notice the term 'Tonic' in the name which is the key to understanding this progression). A7 to Bb major is actually a form of dominant to tonic progression in D minor. The Bb major triad is a variant of the D minor chord. Showing how that works is another topic however so we can just leave it there.

A7(b9) -> Bb Major is D   ->  T LTW